# CakePHP Ajax Login-Validation Failure

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, authentication

Im currently working on a AJAX Login for my application. On the top of the startpage there is a login link which opens a dialog with the loginform when clicked, but I have several problems:

1. When a user entered wrong or no data, no errors are shown
2. When I click on "Login" and the JsHelper updated the "template" and I click again on "Login", he redirects me to http://www.url.com/users/login (which should not happen)
3. When I enter correct logindata, I am logged in, but no redirection is done or a message is shown.

I think I will post now all the needed code to analyse.

**UsersController::login()**

```
    public function login() {
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->render('/elements/users/login');
        }
        return $this->Auth->login();
    }
```

**elements/ajax/login.ctp**
*This is the template for the login dialog.*

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
<fieldset>
  <?php
    echo $this->Session->flash();
    echo $this->Form->create(
          'User', 
          array(
              'controller' => 'users', 
              'action' => 'login'
          )
      );
    echo $this->Form->input(
        'email',
        array(
            'label' => 'E-Mail',
            'style' => 'width: 270px;'
        )
    );
    echo $this->Form->input(
        'password',
        array(
            'style' => 'width: 270px;'
        )
    );
    echo $this->Js->submit(
        'Login', 
        array('url' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ), 
        'update' => '#loginContainer')
    );
    echo $this->Form->end();
  ?>
</fieldset>
```

I think it has something to do with the UsersController::login() but I dont know where to search. So maybe you can help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1261/login) on Auth::login():

> One thing to note is that **you must manually redirect the user** after login as loginRedirect is not called.
>   $this->Auth->login($data) returns 1 on successful login, 0 on a failure

So something roughly similar to:

```
if ($this->Auth->login() === 1) {
    $this->redirect('/');
} else {
    $this->set('status', 'Bad login details');
}
```

*thoroughly untested

Connected with javascript written to handle that.

Comment: Well thanks for the info, I add it to my code, although nothing changed :/. Yesterday I installed DebugKit for CakePHP and when I submit my valid logindata, he shows me "Debug timer info". This is totally confusing. Why is this shown? When I look into "Request" from the DebugKit, the parameter **isAjax** is *off*, but why? O_O

Btw. there are still no errors shown when the login fails :/

Comment: That was more example code, then something fully fledged you could insert into your application.